# Simple Django queryset __icontains search that will find most specific elements first

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm doing a queryset filter for "foo" in a CharField using __ictonains and I want to find the most specific search matches first.

Dataset in database for a certain field named "description":

```
fooal;skdjfkasdgh;alskdjrf
foobar
foo-nstastical
foobariffic
foo-ntastic
foo
```

When I search for:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(description__icontains="foo")
```

The queryset returns the results in some order according to id number (or other factors?):

```
fooal;skdjfkasdgh;alskdjrf
foobar
foo-nstastical
foobariffic
foo-ntastic
```

If I only show the top 5 results I will leave out "foo" which is actually the best match that I want to show first.  How can I give higher weight to better matches in a simple way without implementing a "real heavy duty" search engine like Lucene?  I want an easier queryset filter hack.

This is a crude search engine for a text dataset, the reason it is more important to show foo first when only showing the top N results is that if the person was looking for foobariffic, they could type in more letters.  But there is no way to get "foo" by typing more letters if it is displaced by longer entries.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to look into haystack http://haystacksearch.org/. It is very easy to use, easy to configure (Whoosh backend is pure python, no binary packages) and is quite powerful. Has some nice utilities like highlighting search query. Comes with search view, form and urls. The View is classed based and very easy to extend. If you lack performance with Whoosh, it is easy to switch to xapian based backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a small field, you could potentially sort by field length and get good results.

Given a match, the shortest result is the hardest and most significant match. Wouldn't work for full text of course...

I would be comfortable doing this for an autocomplete username or tag field.

```
foo
bofoo
foobar
barfood
```

**Python sort**

```
# python sort
x = [results]
x.sort(key=len)
```

**Or in SQL**

```
MyModel.objects.extra(select={'myfield_length':'Length(myfield)'}).order_by('myfield_length')
```